# Cookies removed when reloaded - React and Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cookies

**How to I prevent chrome from removing the cookies when browser reload?**

A cookies created when a user created an account shown below and the Expires/Max-age is 1 months later. However, when I reloaded/refreshed the page the cookies was gone. However, the cookies in the post-man was not deleted.
**Domain (Frontend):** http://localhost:3000/

**Domain (Backend):** http://127.0.0.1:5000/

[image]

**Updated (22 Sept 2021):**
[image]

**React:**
This is how I do my fetch request. I set the credentials to `include`.

```
   fetch(domain + "/account/create", {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(inputData),
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
        return(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        setErrorMsg(error.message);
    });
```

**Flask (backend):**

```
      resp = Response(
          response=json.dumps(
              { 'message': 'Account Created', 
                'token': f'{encoded_jwt}'}),
                status=200,
                mimetype="application/json"
            )


      resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
      resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
      resp.set_cookie('token', value=encoded_jwt, httponly= True, expires = TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE, samesite='None', secure=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are all doing it right.
I am just getting some suspect on your TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE it's must be datetime object.

[See the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie)

Check your expires value.

If it's still making problem.

Use flask-login instead. It will going to store your user auth. And manage all your logins it's so easy to use.

Comment: Thank you. I will read about flask-login. The data type is `<class 'datetime.datetime'>` for ` TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE`. This can't solve the problem.